# Always 1 Gremlin Worker Threads Active in DSE Graph

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-enterprise-graph

In my DSE cluster I have these settings: `threadPoolWorker = 32` and `gremlinPool = 64`

However, when I run any kind of gremlin query (heavy queries too), I always see from the Dashboard of the OpsCenter that at most only 1 per node Worker thread is active.

Is that normal?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is normal,.

You will generally never use more than one thread pool worker as

http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/3.2.3/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/server/Settings.html#threadPoolWorker

You probably want to leave threadPoolWorker as the default value.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you changing the defaults for threadPoolWorker and gremlinPool?  Those are typically not adjusted.